# How to pass whole environment from target Linux to client Linux over one ssh session?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, environment-variables

I have script on target Linux (RedHat, PC_A) which I would like to execute from source Linux (RedHat, PC_B) during remote login session.

I'm trying to execute following command :

`[user2@PC_B] ssh <user1>@<PC_A> "cd /home/<user1>; source /home/<user1>/.bashrc; ./<script.sh>;"`

but as soon as I login and execute I'm receiving multiple errors,

"`Environment variable USER1_ROOT not defined
./stoprun: line 6: psrun: command not found
./omcserver: error while loading shared libraries: libocci.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./wdc: error while loading shared libraries: libmutil.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (...)`

Note 1: `<user1>` is already authenticated without the password (added to authorized users on PC_A), there is no problem here; e.g. I can execute `[<user2>@<PC_B> ~]$ ssh <user1>@<PC_A> "cd /home/<user1>; ls -ls; date"` without any errors

Note 2: I'm not concern at all about errors like, `"./stoprun: line 6: psrun: command not found"` nor `"error while loading shared libraries"` (I just showed them as example of the consequence of the problem with passing properly variables between PC_A and PC_B) and I need to pass multiple variables within single ssh session. My main concern is Error message **"Environment variable xxx_xxx not defined"**.

How to properly pass entire environment from target/server (PC_A) to source/client (PC_B) during one single ssh session ?

Note 3: on both hosts (PC_A) and PC_B I already set

```
[root@PC_A ~]# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep User
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

Note 4: same script executes without any error, problem or missing libs when executed from source host (PC_A)

```
[<user1>@<PC_A> ~]$ cd /home/<user1>
[<user1>@<PC_A> ~]$./<script.sh>;
```

/2/
on PC_B added variables in /etc/ssh/ssh_config
PC_B :

```
[root@<PC_B> ~]# cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep SendEnv
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
        SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
        SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
        SendEnv TEST
[root@<PC_B> ~]#
```

/3/ Specified a customized environment variables in ~/.ssh/environment

```
[root@<PC_B> ~]# cat /home/user2/.ssh/environment
LANG=en_us.utf-8  
TEST="test"
[root@<PC_B> ~]#
```

Note: LANG environment variable is already defined on both PC_A and PC_B, so I added one more "independent" variable TEST

/4/ 
executed ssh with adding verbosity -v

```
[user2@<PC_B> ~]$ ssh -v <user1>@<PC_A_IP_Address> "cd /home/<user1>; echo $TEST; echo $LANG"
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <PC_A_IP_Address> [<PC_A_IP_Address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user2/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user2/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '<PC_A_IP_Address>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user2/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user2/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: cd /home/<user1>; echo ; echo en_US.UTF-8

en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.1 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 0
[user2@<PC_B> ~]$
```

/5/ I restarted sshd service on both PC_A and PC_B

```
[root@<PC_A> ~]# service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
[root@<PC_A> ~]#
```

/6/ Checking Environment variables from PC_A
(a) as root user

```
[root@<PC_A> ~]# echo $TEST

[root@<PC_A> ~]# echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

(a) as non-root user

```
[root@<PC_A> ~]# exit
logout
[<user1>@<PC_A> ~]$ echo $TEST

[<user1>@<PC_A> ~]$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
[<user1>@<PC_A> ~]$
```

And here is the issue : somehow only one environment variable is send and it seems immediately replaced within open ssh session by its defined value and while other variable vanished (blank value)

```
   "debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
   debug1: Sending command: cd /home/<user1>; echo ; echo en_US.UTF-8

   en_US.UTF-8"
```

Note #1
I added also all combinations here , and none of them work :

```
[root@<PC_B> ~]# cat /home/user2/.ssh/environment
LANG=en_us.utf-8
TEST=test
[root@<PC_B> ~]#

[root@<PC_B> ~]# cat /home/user2/.ssh/environment
set LANG=en_us.utf-8
set TEST=test
[root@<PC_B> ~]#

[root@<PC_B> ~]# cat /home/user2/.ssh/environment
declare -x  LANG="en_us.utf-8"
declare -x  TEST="test"
[root@<PC_B> ~]#
```

Comment: Likely a problem with the contents of `script.sh`. Also, is the shebang using `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`?

Comment: Thank you @xenoid for comment. Please notice note #4 , script runs without any error from source host (PC_A) . Error shows only during ssh (remote session) from other host (PC_B).   Script starts with `#!/bin/bash` 
`~/.bash_profile` and it is very simply script with copy, cd commands , simple timer loop and executing directly other scripts". Second line with ```~/.bash_profile``` I added for troubleshooting purpose, hoping it will resolve issue. But problem persist even without ```~/.bash_profile``` after shebang.

Comment: @Reda, Yes Reda, you are absolutely correct with your assumption "that the main issue here is due to the environment variables that are not accessible by the script when it gets executed on PC_A." I'm highly appreciate for approaching to my challenge and comprehensive instructions. I followed all the steps BUT unfortunately still it doesn't work for me. I'm adding more details into my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the main issue here is due to the environment variables that are not accessible by the script when it gets executed on PC_A.

Setting ***PermitUserEnvironment yes*** is not enough, you have to explicitly specify which variables to pass, you can do it by :

PS: As an example i have chosen **LANG** variable.

1- Allow the use of environment variables on PC_A by editing ***/etc/ssh/sshd_config*** :

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

2- Adding the variables in ***/etc/ssh/ssh_config*** on PC_B, LANG will consists of the environment variable of the user sending the **ssh** request :

```
SendEnv LANG
```

3- Specify a customized environment variables in ***~/.ssh/environment*** that are independent of the user environment on PC_B :

```
LANG=en_us.utf-8
```

4- Check whether the environment variables were sent successfully by adding verbosity when doing ssh to PC_A :

```
ssh -v ....
```