# How many environment variables can be passed through openssh SendEnv/AcceptEnv

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, environment-variables, openssh

I have added `SendEnv whatever_*` in ~/.ssh/config on the local host and `AcceptEnv LANG LC_* whatever_*` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the remote host.

Now, I'm trying to run some stuff on the remote machine using the environment `whatever_*` environment variables, but there seems to be a problem: It only exports 128 variables.

At first I thought there was some issue in the format of some variables so I started to search for unusual ones (spaces in values, weird characters etc.), thinking that there is a parsing issue or something, but this wasn't it.

Running the script below on multiple ubuntu remote machines resulted in the same thing: 128 exported variables. `env_size_remote` value will vary depending on remote machine (e.g. ~5300, ~4700, ~4300 bytes), so I'm guessing it's not a size issue.

```
for i in {0..150}; do export LC_custom_var_${i}=lc_custom_value_${i}; done

var_num_host=$(printenv | grep LC_ | wc -l)
env_size_host=$(printenv | wc --bytes)

var_num_remote=$(ssh -vvv {user}@{remote_machine} printenv 2> debug.log | grep -c LC_)
env_size_remote=$(ssh {user}@{remote_machine} printenv | wc --bytes)

sent_vars=$(grep -c LC_custom_var debug.log)

echo "Host var num: ${var_num_host}"
echo "Env size host: ${env_size_host}"
echo "Sent vars num: ${sent_vars}"
echo "Remote var num: ${var_num_remote}"
echo "Env size remote: ${env_size_remote}"
```

Script output:

> Host var num: 151
> Env size host: 7994
> Sent vars num: 151
> Remote var num: 128
> Env size remote: 5281

Is there a limit on the maximum number of exported environment variables that can be configured for openssh or something like this?

Both host and remote machines are Ubuntu Linux (18.04 and 20.04). Tried to send from 18 to 18, 18 to 20, 20 to 18 and every time the number of exported variables is 128.

EDIT: using verbose mode, openssh reports sending all custom variables. I have edited the script to also show this.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1531557/how-to-pass-whole-environment-from-target-linux-to-client-linux-over-one-ssh-ses

Comment: @Gantendo thanks, updated the question with info from verbose mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) is the most widely used SSH software. The OpenSSH `sshd` program, which handles the server part of ssh connections, has a hardcoded limit of 128 environment variables for sessions opened by the client. The limit is implemented in a function called `session_env_req()` in [*session.c*](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c#L2090):

```
/* Don't set too many environment variables */
if (s->num_env > 128) {
    debug2("Ignoring env request %s: too many env vars", name);
    goto fail;
}
```

The simplest way to get around that limit would be to build your own copy of `sshd` from the source code, if you know how to do that. OpenSSH is [open source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable) (or ([here](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html))).

You might be able to work around the limit by passing environment variables as part of the command that you execute. Try running this:

```
ssh -vvv {user}@{remote_machine} 'FOO=foo BAR=bar ... printenv'
```

Most shells would interpret that to set the FOO and BAR environment variables for the duration of the command being run. You ought to be able to set a pretty large number of variables this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changed the LOGLEVEL in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to DEBUG2 and "Ignoring env request" messages now appear in there.